# Solid surface of the gas giants

Tags: planets

Given the gravities of gas giants and other similar celestial obejcts, I find it hard to believe that their centers aren't crushed to solid states.

If the gas giants and other similar objects have a solid core.
Why isn't that considered a solid surface for the planet?
Why aren't these then just planets with a very thick atmosphere.

Comment: So by this logic then stars must be solid too since their gravity is even greater

Comment: We're not sure what kind of core giant planets have, but they clearly warrant a classification very different from that of rocks with "apple-skin" atmospheres.

Comment: I believe that Uranus is a plaent about the size of Earth under an ocean 5000 miles thick, which is under an atmosphere 5000 miles thick.  The center of Jupiter is not known, but it could be crushed to a solid state. The Sun is much bigger than all of them. It's center is *really* hot. Even though it is crushed to 150 times the density of water, it is not a solid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think we know for sure that they do have solid cores. It would seem likely, but even the center of the Earth is guesswork, let alone gas giants. But a distinguishing feature would be that a majority of the mass of the planet exists in gas form (esp. large amounts of hydrogen and helium)